# Infinite loop in iterative implementation of QuickSort?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting, octave, quicksort

I'm trying to implement an iterative *QuickSort* using [Lomuto's Partitiong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) method, for that reason I'm trying to implement a *stack* that holds a pair of indexes defining sub-array to be partitioned, using an array of `struct` with two `fields`: `iBeg`, `iEnd` and storing/accessing only the `end` element.

Here is the code:

```
function [sorted] = iterativeQuickSort(A)
% Accepts 1xN unsorted integer array.
% Returns a sorted copy.   
% See also Partition.

  % Starting and ending indexes of unsorted array.
  iBeg = 1;
  iEnd = numel(A);

  % Struct holding A's subarrays star/end indexes resulting from partitioning.
  stack_elem = struct('iBeg', iBeg, 'iEnd', iEnd); 
  stack(end + 1) = stack_elem;  % push on stack

  while numel(stack) != 0

    % Extract last pair of indexes.
    iBeg = stack(end).iBeg;
    iEnd = stack(end).iEnd;
    stack(end) = [];            % pop from stack

    % Get pivot index and array after rearranging elements around the pivot.
    [B, pivotIndex] = Partition(A, iBeg, iEnd);
    A = B;

    % Store indexes of the next two subarrays defined by the pivot index,
    % if their sizes are > 0.
    if pivotIndex - 1 > iBeg 
      stack_elem = struct('iBeg', iBeg, 'iEnd', pivotIndex - 1);
      stack(end + 1) = stack_elem;
    end  

    if pivotIndex + 1 < iEnd
      stack_elem = struct('iBeg', pivotIndex + 1, 'iEnd', iEnd);
      stack(end + 1) = stack_elem;
    end   

  end  

  sorted = A;

end  

function [A, pivotIndex] = Partition (A, iBeg, iEnd)
% Accepts 1xN integer array.  
% Two integers - start and end indexes current subarray of A.
% Returns index of pivot element of current subarray partition
% and A after swaps.

  pivotValue = A(iEnd);      % Choose last element to be pivot.
  pivotIndex = iBeg;         % Initialize pivot index to start of subarray.

  for i = iBeg : iEnd        % Iterate over current subarray
    if A(i) <= pivotValue    % Push elements <= pivot in front of pivot index.   
      % Place element at i-th position before element with pivot index.
      [A(i), A(pivotIndex)] = swapElements(A(pivotIndex), A(i)); 
      % Account for the swap, go to next element.
      pivotIndex = pivotIndex + 1;
    end  
  end  

  % Bring the element used as pivot to its place
  [A(iEnd), A(pivotIndex)] = swapElements(A(pivotIndex), A(iEnd)); 
end  

function [elem2, elem1] = swapElements(elem1, elem2)
  [elem2, elem1] = deal(elem1, elem2);  
end
```

The obviously dumb array assignment `A = B` is made to indicate that element changes due to `swaps` are preserved after the execution of the function `Partition(A, iBeg, iEnd)`.

The current status is what seems to be an infinite loop whose causes I haven't been able to identify, hence any recommendations and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Input:

```
A = [5,   4,   6,   2,   9,   1,   7,   3];
S = iterativeQuickSort(A)
```

Expected Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Current Output: never returns from function, stops only through force brake: ctrl + c.

Note: the implementation and application of the partitioning function differs from the one pointed as possible duplicate.

---

Comment: What input are you using to test?

Comment: @Wolfie What is _"recursion depth"_ in an iterative implementation? Is there a possibility for someone who in the future is having the same problem to seek solution for his iterative implementation in an recursive implementation?

Comment: The algorithms are similar (of course, they're both quicksort) but the implementations are slightly different, since your method isn't recursive. The reason the linked question was failing was the same reason your code is failing, the *symptoms* are different (infinite loop vs. infinite recursion) because of the method, but the solutions are identical. Feel free to leave the question here, since it might help others, but note it may get closed as a duplicate. Side note: you have a typo in your code, your function is called `iterativeQucikSort` not `iterativeQuickSort`

Comment: I agree with @Wolfie on all counts. Leave this one here, it'll still be a good signpost.

Comment: Also worth noting for future readers that your code is written using Octave, not MATLAB. In particular, `!=` is not valid MATLAB syntax, and `~=` should be used for "not equal" if you intend for this to be used with both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Partition` function has an error. If you look at the pseudocode on the Wikipedia page, you'll see that the loop condition is:

```
for j := lo to hi - 1 do
```

The corresponding line in your `Partition` function is:

```
  for i = iBeg : iEnd        % Iterate over current subarray
```

By going to `iEnd` instead of `iEnd - 1`, you're comparing the pivot value to itself and ending up with a pivot index that's off by one. Just change this line to:

```
  for i = iBeg : iEnd-1      % Iterate over current subarray
```